# How to stop a hyperoperation in the middle of (or before) its calculation? - Python

Tags: python, timeout, calculation

I am currently working on translating a bunch of math functions into python to be used for a counting-bot  in discord (as our current counting bot has absolutely no fun maths!).

I have stopped at the realization that I have no way to prevent large calculations from occurring especially when giving the option to interpret Knuth's up-arrow notation and other hyperoperation functions.

I attempted to use a timeout function (as this seemed like the easiest way I could think of working around my problem) but it appears that I misunderstood how KeyboardInterupt works and I now don't think that will help me (or be a good option even if I were to get it to work).

For Example:

```
def knuth(a,n,b):
try:
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return a**b
    return knuth(a, n-1, knuth(a,n,b-1))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Your number is too big yo!")
    exit()
#for example knuth(5,2,5) = 5**5**5**5**5 <- I really don't want to calculate anything that big.
```

I am assuming this is a very common problem among those who do math in python but all of my searching has come up with is ways of implementing a timeout which doesn't seem to help. Is there a way to detect a super massive calculation is about to occur and stop it before it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I solved my own problem but it is a very convoluted workaround and probably contains really bad coding practices...

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Empty #im on python 3 which apparently means queue is lowercased :)  

def knuth(a,n,b):
    if b == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return a**b
    return knuth(a, n-1, knuth(a,n,b-1))
    
    def queuebuff(q,a,n,b): #this and def x() were needed for whatever reason for the
    q.put(knuth(a,n,b)) #queue to work, otherwise I would time out... not sure why
                        #couldnt for the life of me get it to work without it.
def x(q,a,n,b):         #Also I was just frustrated, this will get renamed to
    return (q,a,n,b)    #something more meaningful once I figure out what it is doing
                        #and why I need it for the queue to work...
def queue(a,n,b):
    try:
        q=mp.Queue()
        p = mp.Process(target=queuebuff, args=x(q,a,n,b)) #I know I didn't put this
        p.start()                                         #behind a name gate. Wasn't
        Queuedval = q.get(timeout=5)                      #sure what to do if it was.
        while not q.empty(): #this just dumps any other queued items in case something
            q.get(timeout=5) #goes wrong... no clue if this is good practice.
        p.join()
        return Queuedval
    except Empty:
        print('calculation too large stop it!')
        p.kill() #I cant join the process or it will hang so this was my solution. 
        print('multiprocess closed!')
    print('children active: ',mp.active_children()) #check for children and parents
    print('parents active: ',mp.parent_process())   #seems like it works fine ?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question

You can set a checkup like so:
just choose your tolerance

```
tolerance = 10000000000000
def knuth(a,n,b):
    try:
        if b == 0:
            return 1
        if n == 1:
            return a**b
        if knuth(a, n-1, knuth(a,n,b-1)) > tolerance:
            return 'too big'
        return knuth(a, n-1, knuth(a,n,b-1))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Your number is too big yo!")
        exit()
```

Now ideally you would like to automatically determine what the tolerance before it gets too big and things start hanging, but for now specifying a large number is a simple solution

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that the tolerance will only catch if the computation is not to the point where it crashes python which is hard to put a limit depending on the amount of arrows implemented. Sometimes the first iteration can give 100 and the second is 10E+100000 digits long.